# Does every continuous function have an order of vanishing?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity, asymptotics

I am trying to understand in what ways we can characterise growth of continuous functions around a point. One particular way to do so is by comparing a functions growth to a power of $x$ as follows.

For a continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ define its order of vanishing (at $x=0$) to be the number $0\leq \alpha \leq \infty$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}\right) =\gamma \neq \cases{0 \\ \pm \infty} $$
i.e. the $\alpha$ so the above limit is defined, finite and non-zero.

In the case for a function $f(x)$ where $\frac{f(x)}{x^n} \to 0 \quad \forall n \in[0,\infty)$ define the order of vanishing of $f(x)$, namely $\alpha$, to be $\infty$.

For example with these definitions $\alpha=\infty$ when $f(x)=\exp \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as then $f(x)$ would grow slower than any power of $x$ around $x=0$.

**My question is**: Does the order of vanishing always exist for each continuous function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$? i.e. is this quantity well defined?

If not then are there extra conditions should I stipulate on $f$ to guarantee existence?

My thoughts on the matter as are follows,

1. If such an $\alpha$ exists it is necessarily unique, for if $\beta<\alpha$ then $$\frac{f(x)}{x^\beta}=\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}\cdot x^{\alpha-\beta} \to 0$$ since by assumption the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}$ is finite and non-zero. Hence $\beta$ cannot be an order of vanishing for $f$. Similarly if $\beta>\alpha$ then $$\frac{f(x)}{x^\beta}=\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}\cdot \frac{1}{x^{\beta-\alpha}} \to \pm \infty$$ again, $\beta$ cannot be an order of vanishing of $f$. Therefore if $\alpha$ exists it is unique.
2. We cannot have $\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\to \pm \infty \quad \forall n \in [0,\infty)$ Since for $n=0$ this would imply $f(0)$ non finite.
3. I suspect the existence of such an $\alpha$ may have a topological proof, maybe we can partition the domain of $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$ up into parts $S$ and $L$, i.e. $[0,\infty)=S \cup L$ where

$$S:=\bigg\{ \alpha \in [0,\infty) \bigg | \frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha} \to \pm \infty \text{ as } x \to 0 \bigg \}$$

$$L:=\bigg\{ \alpha \in [0,\infty) \bigg | \frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha} \to 0 \text{ as } x \to 0 \bigg \}$$

Maybe this violates the connectivity of $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: No. Let $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$

Comment: @Justauser You should convert this comment into an answer...

Comment: Changing variables to $1/x$, the study of order of vanishing at $0$ becomes the study of rate of growth at $\infty$.  G.H. Hardy wrote a book collecting the 19th century work on this topic.  *Orders of Infinity, the 'Infinitärcalcül' of Paul Du Bois-Reymond* (Cambridge, 1924)  I see that Amazon.com has many versions of this for sale.  Probably any mathematics library has it, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have commented, $f(x) = x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ with extended defintion $f(0)=0$ is a counter example. Intuitively, we may want $f(x)$ to have $1$ as the order of vanishing.

We can do this by defining the order of vanishing to be $$\sup\{\alpha:\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha}}=0\}$$

Note that the set includes $\alpha=0$ (if we assume $f(0)=0$, i.e. $f(x)$ indeed vanishes at $0$), hence nonempty and $\sup$ exists (could be $\infty$). This defintion is clearly the same as yours if exists.

This definition is equivalent to the following one:

$$\inf \{\alpha: \limsup_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}=\infty\}$$

If the set is empty, then $\inf$ is understood to be $\infty$.

Using these definitions, the $g(x)$ constructed by @Saucy O'Path has $0$ as its order of vanishing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your example very clearly demonstrates why the definition of order of vanishing in the question is not very robust.  If I understand correctly, the definition you have given *is* robust in the sense that even if we cannot find a power of $x$ that $f(x)$ vanishes like, we can still assign $f(x)$ an order of vanish of $0$ or $\infty$ owing to the $\sup$ in your definition?

Comment: Yes. And even if it's not $0$ or $\infty$, the limit $f(x)/x^\alpha$ may not exist like in your def. But it's not a very useful one. In general, just like we can have series that converges arbitrarily fast/slow, we can also have $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ arbitrarily fast/slow that is not necessarily comparable with any power function. (If we have a good useful definition of orde of vanishing such as yours, then we would not need so many tests for series convergence or L'Hôpital's rule: We just compare their order of vanishing and compute $\gamma$.)

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment! To clarify, in the above $\sup$ definition of vanishing you say $\alpha=0$ is in the set which makes the limit $f(x)/x^\alpha$ equal to $0$. In the case $\alpha=0$ does the limit not just become the limit of $f(x)$ which is not generically $0$?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I was thinking of only $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=0$, for otherwise, it doesn't vanish at $0$, so "order of vanishing" is sort of misleading, but of course we can indeed include $f(x)$ with $f(0)\not=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\log \lvert x\rvert}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x =0\end{cases}$ satisfies $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left\lvert\lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha}g(x)\right\rvert=\begin{cases}\infty&\text{if }\alpha>0\\ 0&\text{if }\alpha=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Also a previous comment by @Justauser provided another example:
$$ h(x)=\begin{cases} x \sin \frac 1x,& x \ne 0\\ 0, & x = 0\end{cases}$$
In that case
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|h(x)|}{|x|^{\alpha}} = \begin{cases} 0, & 0 \leq \alpha < 1\\ n.d., & \alpha = 1\\ \infty, &\alpha >1\end{cases}
$$